# Flutter: Encrypted SqlLite database

Tags: android, ios, flutter

in our Flutter application we are looking for a way to encrypt our sql lite database.

Actually it seems that there is no way to accomplish this, any one has a solution to complete this task?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it? What attack are you trying to protect yourself / the app against?

Comment: The client is requesting that all the data saved database on the device are encrypted

Comment: @ArthurAttout there is not a solution on that answer

Comment: have you read through the top answer and the comments?

Comment: yes, if you found the concrete solution, please tell me where it is